# Display related data from database based on dropdown selection JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

In my task I want to select one name from drop down. Then I want to print the technology related to that name in other div tag. I don't know how to do this. I successfully get data from data base for dropdown option. Here is my code.

```html
candidate name:
<select name="candidate_id" class="form-control" id="can_name" value="<?php echo set_value('candidate_id');?>"palceholder="candidate full name" required>
    <option></option>
    <?php foreach ($candidate as $r): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $r->candidate_id; ?>"><?php echo $r->candidate_name." "; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</select>

<div class="error"><?php echo form_error("candidate_name");?></div><br>
<div></div><br> <!-- here I want to print technology related to canididate name -->
```

Comment: related technology is comes from where? other database or its static

Comment: one table holds the name and technology for candidate. from there the technology name will print. but dont know how to do it

Comment: you should use candidate id, which are common to both the tables. just set the click event for dropdown value. it will pass the value of each candidate id. at the other end you can create list of div [each div has id refers to candidate] with the information of candidate technology[inline style with display none]. add onChange event function, just do show that div and hide all other divs. i hope you got it.

Comment: means you have only one table and you are fetching candidate name from it and then you want that on selecting condidate his technology should come?

Comment: @mamta yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

let's use the jQuery library, as this will simplify the syntax of what you want to do considerably.

You include it in your page like this:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will pull in the most recent minified version of the 1.x branch of the library.

Then you need a select. I was about to say, let's use below ex.

Let's use a select anyway, you can change it if it isn't correct:

```
 <label for="meetingPlace">Meeting place: </label>  
   <select id="meetingPlace">
   <option>Please select</option>
   <option>Buckingham Palace</option>
   <option>The White House</option>
   <option>Mount Everest</option>
 </select>
```

With that in place you need to hook into the select's on change event.
you can do this in your JavaScript:

```
 $("#meetingPlace").on("change", function(){
 // This code will fire every time the user selects something
 })
```

All this does is select the element with an id of "#meetingPlace" and declare an anonymous function which should be run every time the user selects something different.

As a final step for this post, let's have the JS output what the user selected to the page.

Create a div with an id of "results":

```
  <div id="results"></div>
```

Then within the onchange callback add the following code:

```
var selected = $(this).val();
$("#results").html("You selected: " + selected);
```

What this does is assign the value of the selected option element to a variable, then set the innerHTML of the results  accordingly.